# Cancelling a subscription in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, rxjs

On the load of component I am subscribing to an array of values and showing the same in List and Drop Down which is working fine.
Then I added "Add button" which is adding object to an array and showing the same in a List.

Issue is like even when I am unsubscribing from the subscription even then it is adding the value when I am clicking on add button, could any please let me know why this is happening

Plunker : https://embed.plnkr.co/CoZCakFsx5q8GBWDBZ24/

Below is my code

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 import {PhoneService} from './phone.service'
 import { ISubscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

 @Component({
   selector:'phone-list',
   template:`
     <ul>
       <li *ngFor='let phone of phones'>
         <a [routerLink]="['/phone',phone.id]">
           {{phone.name}}
         </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
     <select>
       <option *ngFor='let phone of phones' value={{phone.name}}>
         {{phone.name}}
       </option>
     </select>
     <button (click)='add()'>Add</button>
  `
})

export class PhoneListComponent {

  private phones;
  private phone$:ISubscription

  constructor(private ps: PhoneService) {

    this.phone$=this.ps.getPhoneDetails()
      .subscribe((data)=> { 
        this.phones=data;console.log(data)
      });
    }

 add() {
   this.phone$.unsubscribe();
   this.ps.addPhone(); 
 }
}
```

And service code

```
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

  export interface Phone {
    id:number;
    name:string;
  }

 @Injectable()
 export class PhoneService {
   private phoneList : <Phone>[] = [{
     name:'Huwaei',
     id:1
   },{
     name:'Apple',
     id:2
   }]

   getPhoneDetails() {
     return Observable.of(this.phoneList);
   }

  getPhone(id) {

    return this.getPhoneDetails().map(phones=>
     phones.find(phone=>phone.id==id)
    );
  }

   addPhone() {
     this.phoneList.push({name:'dummy',id:3});
   }

 }
```

Comment: Can you just do .first() of rxjs? So you won't have to unsubscribe and its just one?

Comment: Hi, consider formatting your code next time if you want someone to be willing to read it and help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the changes of your `addPhone` method even if you unsubscribe beforehand because your method manipulates the array that's been used within your component.

Instead you should copy your existing array and add the new element to the copied array. By using the spread operator this could be as easy as:

```
addPhone()
{
    this.phoneList = [ ...this.phoneList, {name:'dummy', id: 3}];
}
```

Comment: So the data which I am getting from my subscribe method it is returning original Array as it is and as Array are passed by reference as it is Object in JavaScript values are getting appended to original array, I thought when I am converting Array to Observable it will put some wrapper on Array or it will create stream of that to which we can subscribe, which is not the case

Comment: Even if RxJS and Observables are looking like something magically, at the bottom it is just a callback mechanism that forwards the given values without applying any pixie dust to it.